# If the array has more then 10 elements ... then what?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a top 10 list right here. The list contains all the IPs who visited the domain (out of my log files) and my code below gives me the top 10 IPs of them.

But I want it more dynamically. Like if there are more then 10 different IPs, give me just the 10 IPs that appear the most. If the amount of different IPs is less then 10, just give me all the IPs there are.

The code for this:

```
$all_ips = array_count_values($ip_array);
arsort($all_ips);
$count = count($all_ips);
$keys = array_keys($all_ips);
$topTenIp = array();
$count = $count -1;

for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++){
    if($count < 9){
        $topTenIp[] = $keys[$i];
    }else{
        $topTenIp[] = $keys[$i];
    }
}
```

This works okay but not perfect. If the amount of IPs is below 10, it gives me all the IPs there are. But if there are more then 10, it doesn't give me the 10 most appearing IPs, it just gives me all IPs of the log script.

I hope you understood what I was trying to say. I'm from Germany, so my English isn't that good.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Do you have the number of times an IP visited the website ?

Comment: why both code same in if and else? $topTenIp[] = $keys[$i]?

Comment: Your for loop should run only 9 times `for($i=0;$i<9;$i++)`

Comment: öhm.. thats just a mistake.. i have tried it but it havent worked.. but i dont know what else i should write there

Comment: "the list gets me from my log files all the IP" - directly from the (flat) file? Or is there a (relational) database involved somewhere?

Comment: i have the number of IP's that visited the page ( $count ) -

Comment: Just for clarification: $all_ips "looks" like `array( '127.0.0.1'=>45, '10.0.0.9'=>32, 172.16.0.4=>'16', ....)` ?

Comment: yes exactly - it looks like you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing isn't logical. Say `$all_ips` is 30 then every 30 iterations will execute in the else. Resulting in a array of 30 ip's.

You'll need to change your if and else part.

```
    for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++){
        if($i < 9){
            $topTenIp[] = $keys[$i];
        } else {
             break; //Break out of the loop
        }
    }
```

Comment: damn this works just like perfect :O I'll use that, thanks a lot!

Comment: öhm.. maybe you could help me with another thing.. this works just perfect - i tried it with a domain that have much more then 10 different IP's and with a domain that have less then 10.. and it works - but i really dont know, why there is always one an empty line between before the last IP ( if the domain have less than 10 IP's ) --- there is just an empty space and in the next line the last IP o.o

Comment: this isn't logical either – why do the loop till $count if you never go past 9? could be for($i=0; $i <= 9; $i++) { if (!isset($keys[$i])) break; $topTenIp[] = $keys[$i]; } but using array_slice() is way shorter anyway

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see how this is related to Laravel at all, but anyway:

```
$counted = array_count_values($ipArray);
arsort($counted);
$top = array_keys(array_slice($counted, 0, 10));
```

Would be a faster, simpler way to get top 10 items, given that your source $ipArray is a simple array of IP addresses.

Comment: it really isnt related to laravel.. but i havent found a solution in laravel for that :D but i'm using laravel as my framework :) 

thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing same code in if and else condition.

You can do like this:

```
for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++){
    if($i < 9){
         $topTenIp[] = $keys[$i];
    }          
}
```

Comment: In this answer if you have more than 10 items in the $keys array then your $topTenIp array will just be empty.

Answer (score -1):

please try the following

```
    $all_ips = array_count_values($ip_array);
    arsort($all_ips);
    $count = count($all_ips);
    $keys = array_keys($all_ips);
    $topTenIp = array();
    $count = $count -1;
    for($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++){
        if($count < 9){
            $topTenIp[] = $keys[$i];
        }else{
            $topTenIp[] = $keys[$i];
        }

        if( $i >= 9  )
        {
           break;
        }
    }
```

in your code there is no check given if number count is grater than 10 , so please give a check , i have updated my answer

Comment: You need to *explain* your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Also you already have a variable that keeps track of a count ($i) so why not use that instead of creating another variable.

Comment: i have done the corrections and thank you for you valuable suggestions